# Convert 8-bit image to 4-bit image OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I manually convert 8-bit (CV_8U) image to 4-bit image? Here is the simple example for loading image.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    for (int r = 0; r < image.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < image.cols; ++c)
        {
            // What to do here??
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe there is another way to convert.

Comment: Can you explain why you need 4 bit image? What you want to do? Do you need a 2 byte per pixel image? Values in the 4 bit are for each single channel? Values are pixel values or indices to a colortable?

Comment: It's only exercise, I need 4 bit per pixel, values are pixel values, yes for single channel

Comment: Since it's exercise, you should try to do it yourself ;D. I'll create an image of type `CV_16UC1` (or `Mat1w`), so that each "pixel" has 16 bits. Then you need to get b,g,r components of each pixel from your original image, that will be 8 bits each. Divide each b,g,r by 16, so that the values will be scaled to fit 4 bits. Then use some shift / logical operations to get each pixel in the destination image formed as: 0000bbbb ggggrrrr. The result will be a 16 bit per pixel, with each channel information of 4 bits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shift right r, g and b by 4, and change each value of original image. Is this correct?

Comment: Like this for r value:  `image.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[0] = image.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[0] >> 4;`